# 404 Not Found (nginx/1.10.2)

Tags: error, 404

After I log into Magento (using mozilla firefox), go to Dashboard/Catalog/Manage Products. 
I will edit a product and click save and I get this error. 
[image]

Can anyone help? I cannot do anything to my site, not even add new products.

Comment: The image you put in your post is broken. Can you update your post with an updated image file or the text of the error?

Comment: you have wrong config or custom module

Comment: @MagenX: I do not know what the means. I am the only person on my team who is experiencing this. Can you provide more details? I have lost an entire week of work by not being able to resolve this. The developer who truncated the site is MIA and we are hosed right now.

Comment: @JonathanPellerin: what do you mean the image is broke?? that is the image I get whenever I edit or try to add a product. 404 Not Found.

Comment: oh it's working now. The image you linked in your question was broken when I initially saw this.
Since you mentioned a developer truncating the site in another comment, I think you should have a look at the ACL rules under System > Permissions > Rules, they might be broken.

Comment: @JonathanPellerin Thank You for this. I have asked the admin to look into that for me. it is so strange because no one else on my team is experiencing this issue. Is there a way to troubleshoot or look to see if my browser is blocking these pages from loading? I use Chrome and have also tried Forefox and I cannot get the site to fully load into the dashboard in Chrome and then Firefox is erroring out too

Comment: Let me know if the ACL fixes it - I really can't think of anything other than that. I'd have to look at your code to figure it out :P